# Tiingo Client API is pulling data outside of range by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, tiingo

```
startDate = '2018-06-12 00:30:00'
endDate = '2019-06-12 17:35:00'

articles = client.get_news(tickers=['GOOGL'],
                            sources=['washingtonpost.com'],
                            startDate = startDate,
                            endDate = endDate)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(articles)
df2.head()
```

This is the code and when it outputs at 'df2.head()', the first article is from 2020. Has anyone gone through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As per the `API` documentation

  - *News API allows 3 Months of queryable history and all data going forward. For commercial clients who require more history (up to 15 years available), please contact `sales@tiingo.com`.*
  - https://api.tiingo.com/account/billing/pricing

Comment: Thank you so much, I would have never guessed to look there